# Adf costing for parallel running pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have main adf pipeline which has several child pipelines. Those pipelines are getting data from different sources from azure blob and loading data into different snowflake tables.
Individually each child pipeline run for average of **4** mins. However they are running parallelly
under main pipeline where main pipeline runs for around **8** mins. If I sum each child pipeline execution time it will total up to **40** mins.
So will I be charged for **8** mins of parallel execution or **40** mins of pipeline run based on total of all child pipeline runs.

I have already checked in cost-analysis and it does not give costing based on individual pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I have validated the scenario asked in the question . It seems adf charges for each pipeline run . I recreated the scenario as below

1. Created one main pipeline and ran 3 child pipelines parallelly within main pipeline for couple of days. Main pipeline ran for 17 mins
2. Removed 2 child pipelines and ran Main pipeline with 1 child pipeline for couple of days. Main pipeline ran for 17 mins.

[image: Cost analysis for ADF]

In 2nd scenario it cost around 1.490376279 INR per day while it cost 8.141834833 INR in scenario 1. This validates that ADF costing happens for each pipeline irrespective of how it runs